# Undefined operator for if function - Java

Tags: java, function, if-statement, undefined

I am trying to write a simple if function that calculates if someone is eligible for a bonus or not. This is done in an "Employee" class that has fields:

```
private int id = 0;
private String forename;
private String surname;
private Salary salary;
private CompanyPosition companyPosition;
```

Here is the IF :

```
public boolean eligibleForBonus() {    
    boolean isEligible = true;
    if (salary >= 40000) {
        isEligible = true;
    }
    return isEligible;
}
```

Salary is another class with a field

```
private double salary = 0.0;
```

(also has all getters and setters defined)

However, I get an error on the line with the IF, that says:

> The operator >= is undefined for the argument type Salary, int

Comment: The message says it all. What should if (banana >= apple) test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to call your getter to retrieve the salary from the `salary` object of type `Salary`:

```
if ( salary.getSalary() >= 40000)
```

Note that your whole method could be written more simply like this:

```
public boolean eligibleForBonus(){
    return salary.getSalary() >= 40000;
}
```

As a side note, your current method does not work properly because you initialized the `isEligible` flag to `true` instead of `false` (and so the method will always return `true` no matter what the salary is).

You could also introduce a constant to hold the minimum salary required for a bonus and use it elsewhere. This avoids using magic numbers and it documents properly what the `40000` number is supposed to mean.

```
private static final double MINIMUM_SALARY_FOR_BONUS = 40000;

public boolean eligibleForBonus(){
    return salary.getSalary() >= MINIMUM_SALARY_FOR_BONUS;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the swift answer!
You really cleared up my understanding there and took it one step further.
I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`salary` is a object reference and you cant compare a object reference with an primitive type (unless its Wrapper).

You should compare like `if (salary.getSalary() >=40000)`

Comment: I need to have over 15 rep :(( i will come back and do so when I'm over 15 rep !!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to check if your object `Salary` is >= 40000. You need to use the getter of the `salary` member of you `Salary` class.

```
if (salary.getSalary() >= 40000) {
    isEligible = true;
}
```

Also you don't really need the boolean and the if in your method:

```
public boolean eligibleForBonus() {
    return salary.getSalary() >= 40000
}
```

You shouldn't initialise `String` variable with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `salary.getSalary() >= 40000`, Salary is an object, you want to compare the value of its field "salary" (strange naming though).

Btw : you will never return false, your init is wrong and useless.